# When clicked EditText on any fragment foucs automatically changes to 1st fragment EditText in viewpager when same xml used for all fragments rendering

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I have an XML layout which is used for rendering all the fragments dynamically in the view pager scroll view and in the fragment layout i have a Edit Text Box and when i click on the edit text in the second or thrid fragment immediately the keyboad opens and foucs is changed to the first fragment edit box.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentPageTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_header_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibClose"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_button_close"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:text="123"
                android:textColor="@color/inforGray6"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainscrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"

            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_layout">


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using the scroll view layout to addView() the final layout in the UI is rendered and when setting the scroolview visibility to gone then only text field renders on ui and focus change is not happening.